# Easiest way to Regulating 12V-16V to 12V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I want to power the circuit with 4 lithium-ion batteries, 3.7V each. In total, they should supply 12V to 16.8V, I would like to power a motor with this power supply, the motor driver needs 9-12V. What is the easiest approach I could take? I am thinking about regulating the voltage with either zener diodes or LM7812, but I am not exactly sure how would they perform.

Comment: How much current does your motor take?

Comment: The motor driver would take approximately 2A

Answer (score 3):

If you want to simplify your life, just remove one battery, then you are between 9 and 12.6 V, which should be just fine.

If you are planning on doing PWM (control) (ie speed control) anyway, and this is a hobby project, then you can just use your raw battery voltage, and set a PWM value low enough such that the average voltage is below 12 V (so bellow about 70 % when your battery is full).

If you really want to regulate the voltage, then it would be easiest to use rather distinct voltage ranges (for example to use a 6 V motor): then you can use a buck converter to regulate your voltage properly without too much losses. Note however that as soon as you start regulating your voltage, there are many parameters to take into account if you don't want to destroy some of your components:

- if your use PWM, then make sure your regulator can handle the varying current:
  it helps if you add additional capacitors between the regulator and the H-bridge, and if you use a high enough PWM frequency to keep current nearly constant
- you can't use regenerative breaking (excepted with special converters):
  the energy can't go back to the batteries (and might destroy things trying). If you need to dissipate the power, you will need a dedicated resistor
- be careful if the motor is externally driven (either by inertia if stopping it brutally, or my hand):
  it will generate voltage that your converter might be unable to handle

Answer (score 2):

At full battery, a linear regulator like the LM7812 would dissipate (16.8-12)*2 watts, or almost 10 W.

You would need a good heatsink and you'd severely impact your battery life.  Zeners would be worse.

A buck converter or potentially a buck-boost converter would be the most efficient solution to regulating the voltage. You could get a kind of open-loop speed control by adjusting the output voltage.

However, using the raw battery voltage and PWM to adjust the effective voltage or even to create a closed-loop speed control is also an option and may be simpler and even more efficient than using a DC-DC converter.

Answer (score 1):

The motor will be happy running from a PWM waveform, so all you need is a PWM controller that keeps the duty cycle such that the DC average output voltage is where you need it.

Regulating DC for motor applications is usually unnecessary. Linear regulators like 7812 not only waste power, but need 3V of dropout voltage to work at all. So, the 7812 would be regulating when the input is 15V, but below that it'd drop out of regulation.

A basic hysteretic PWM regulator is just a comparator and either a single semiconductor switch, or a half-bridge driver. Hysteretic here means that it keeps the output voltage between two voltage levels on purpose, and ramps up and down between them very quickly, so the motor - due to its electromechanical inertia - acts as if an average value DC voltage was driving it.

Comment: Just to add, the 7812 is literally almost 40 years old - modern regulators (i.e. anything made in the last 15 y) will have a far lower dropout voltage and quiescent current.